# Progressive webapp with shell cached still not behaving as desired?

Tags: reactjs, offline-caching, progressive-web-apps, sw-precache, sw-toolbox

I have used Sw-precache in my React app to pre-cache my built assets(i.e vendor.js, app.js and, icons). however, the result is less than desirable.  On page reload my app assets are all fetched again(from service worker), but never the less everything disappears (page goes blank) for a moment and assets appear. 
[Screen capture of my app on page reload](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5LPkXe_6li5QXlxbjdiS3F1Rms). In comparison, here is an app [the Session](https://thesession.org/) from a list from https://pwa.rocks/. That truly has a offline cached that even on reload does not re-fetch the static assets. [Here is also a screen capture of the session app on page reload](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5LPkXe_6li5R05ZcVFmRDUxWWM). I'm positive there is something I am Not doing. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

It could simple be that your HTML is returning and empty page and it takes time for the Javascript to run and populate the DOM with content, where as The Session is returning the HTML populated from the service worker.